# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#195) at 0x00913A10. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

i have the following code on VS for writing a polynomial calculator class. 
.h file is as below

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class Poly {
private:
    int coefficient=0;
    int largest_exponent=0;
    int* array = nullptr;
    //string input;
public:
    //constructor
    Poly(int coefficient, int largest_exponent);
    Poly(int coefficient); // assume the exponent or power is 0
    Poly(); // empty constructor 0 coeffecient and 0 exponent
    Poly(const Poly& poly); //copy constructor

    //destructoer
    ~Poly();
    int getCoeff(int num);
    void setCoeff(int coeff, int exp);
    //delete and valgrind

    //Overload

    Poly operator*(const Poly &poly) const;
    Poly operator+(const Poly &poly) const;
    //Poly operator+(const Poly &poly);
    Poly operator-(const Poly &poly) const;

    Poly operator*=(const Poly &poly) const;
    Poly operator+=(const Poly &poly) const;
    Poly operator-=(const Poly &poly) const;

    Poly operator=(const Poly &poly) const;
    Poly operator==(const Poly &poly) const;
    Poly operator!=(const Poly &poly) const;

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Poly &poly);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, Poly &poly);
};
```

and my .cpp file is as below

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Poly.h"


Poly::Poly(int coefficient, int largest_exponent) { // largest component must be +ve value 
    this->largest_exponent = largest_exponent;
    this->coefficient = coefficient;

    this->array = new int[largest_exponent+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= largest_exponent; i++) {
        this->array[i] = 0;    // Initialize all elements to zero.
    }
    this->array[largest_exponent] = coefficient;
}

Poly::Poly(int coefficient) { // assume the exponent or power is 0
    this->largest_exponent = 0;
    this->coefficient = coefficient;

    this->array = new int[1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        this->array[i] = 0;    // Initialize all elements to zero.
    }
    this->array[0] = coefficient;
}

Poly::Poly() { // empty constructor 0 coeffecient and 0 exponent
    this->coefficient = 0;
    this->largest_exponent = 0;

    //this->array = new int[1];
    this->array = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) {
        this->array[i] = 0;    // Initialize all elements to zero.
    }   
}

Poly::Poly(const Poly& poly) { //copy constructor
    this->coefficient = poly.coefficient;
    this->largest_exponent = poly.largest_exponent;

    this->array = new int[poly.largest_exponent+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= poly.largest_exponent; i++) {
        this->array[i] = poly.array[i];    // Initialize all elements to zero.
    }
}

Poly::~Poly() {
    cout << "deleting Polynomial array" << endl;
    delete[] array;
    array = nullptr; //or delete array;
}

int Poly::getCoeff(int num) {
    int coeff = this->array[num];
    if (coeff > -33686019) {
        cout << "coeff of power " << num << " of P is: " << coeff << endl;
        return this->array[num];
    }
    else {
        cout << "this Exponent does not exist in the polynomial" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

void Poly::setCoeff(int coeff, int exp) {
    int* newarray = new int[(abs(exp)) + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= (abs(exp));i++) {
        newarray[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= this->largest_exponent;i++) {
        newarray[i] = this->array[i];
    }
    newarray[(abs(exp))] = coeff;
    this->array = newarray;
    //this->array[abs(exp)] = coeff; 
    if ((abs(exp)) > this->largest_exponent) {
        this->largest_exponent = (abs(exp));
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Poly &poly) {
    bool flag = false;

    for (int i = poly.largest_exponent; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (poly.array[i] > 0 && i > 1) {
                os << " +" << poly.array[i] << "x^" << i;
                flag = true;
            }
            if (poly.array[i] < 0 && i > 1) {
                os << " " << poly.array[i] << "x^" << i;
                flag = true;
            }
            if (poly.array[i] > 0 && i == 1) {
                os << " +" << poly.array[i] << "x";
                flag = true;
            }
            if (poly.array[i] < 0 && i == 1) {
                os << " " << poly.array[i] << "x";
                flag = true;
            }
            if (poly.array[i] > 0 && i == 0) {
                os << " +" << poly.array[i];
                flag = true;
            }
            if (poly.array[i] < 0 && i == 0) {
                os << " " << poly.array[i];
                flag = true;
            }
    }
    if (flag == false) {
        os << " 0";
    }
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &is, Poly &poly) {  
    poly.largest_exponent = 0;  
    int * temparray=new int[0]; 
    int coeff;
    int exp;
    cout << "Enter terms for polynomial A.  Enter a coefficient " << endl;
    if (std::cin >> coeff >> exp) {
        if (coeff != -1 && exp != -1) {
            poly.array[exp] = coeff;
            if (poly.largest_exponent < coeff)
                poly.largest_exponent = coeff;
        }

    }
    return is;
}

Poly Poly::operator*(const Poly &poly) const {
    Poly * temp = new Poly();
    temp->largest_exponent = poly.largest_exponent + this->largest_exponent;

    for (int k = 0; k <= temp->largest_exponent; k++) {
        temp->array[k] = 0;    // Initialize all elements to zero.
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= this->largest_exponent; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= poly.largest_exponent; j++) {
            temp->array[i + j] += (this->array[i] * poly.array[j]);
        }
    }
    return *temp;
}

Poly Poly::operator+(const Poly &poly) const {
    Poly * temp = new Poly();
    int smallest_exponent;
    if (this->largest_exponent >= poly.largest_exponent) {
        temp->largest_exponent = this->largest_exponent;
        smallest_exponent = poly.largest_exponent;
        for (int i = 0; i <= temp->largest_exponent; i++) {
            temp->array[i] = this->array[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        temp->largest_exponent = poly.largest_exponent;
        smallest_exponent = this->largest_exponent;
        for (int i = 0; i <= temp->largest_exponent; i++) {
            temp->array[i] = poly.array[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= smallest_exponent; i++) {

        temp->array[i] = poly.array[i] + this->array[i];
    }
    return *temp;
}

Poly Poly::operator-(const Poly &poly) const {
    Poly * temp = new Poly();
    int smallest_exponent;

    if (this->largest_exponent >= poly.largest_exponent) {
        temp->largest_exponent = this->largest_exponent;
        smallest_exponent = poly.largest_exponent;
        for (int i = 0; i <= temp->largest_exponent; i++) {
            temp->array[i] = this->array[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        temp->largest_exponent = poly.largest_exponent;
        smallest_exponent = this->largest_exponent;
        for (int i = 0; i <= temp->largest_exponent; i++) {
            temp->array[i] = poly.array[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= smallest_exponent; i++) {
        temp->array[i] = this->array[i] - poly.array[i];
    }

    if (this->largest_exponent < poly.largest_exponent) {
        for (int i = smallest_exponent+1; i <= poly.largest_exponent; i++) {
            temp->array[i] = temp->array[i]*-1;
        }
    }
    return *temp;   
}
```

and this is my driver .cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Poly.h"

int main()
{
    Poly A(-5,1);
    int x = A.getCoeff(1);
    A.setCoeff(7,3);
    A.setCoeff(6,2);
    Poly B(2);
    B.setCoeff(8,2);
    B.setCoeff(8,0);
    Poly C; 
    Poly D(A);
    cout << A << endl;
    cout << B << endl;
    cout << C << endl;
    cout << D << endl;
    Poly E = B + A;
    cout << E << endl;
    Poly F = A-B;
    cout << F << endl;
    Poly G = B-A;   
    cout << G << endl;
    Poly H = B * A;
    cout << H << endl;
    cout << endl;
    //Poly I;
    //cin >> I;
    //cout << I << endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Whenever itry to run this code, i get the below error even though when i click continue the results seem to be fine. Anyone has an idea where am i messing up the memory?

Debug Error!

Program:

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#195) at 0x00A03A10.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
Critical error detected c0000374
Poly.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Exception thrown at 0x77DC61E4 (ntdll.dll) in Poly.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77DE2378).
Unhandled exception at 0x77DC61E4 (ntdll.dll) in Poly.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77DE2378).

'Poly.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Poly.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Poly.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Poly.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Poly.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Poly.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Poly.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Poly.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Poly.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown at 0x77D21796 (ntdll.dll) in Poly.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: Why do you mark all your operators as `const`, even assignment? I guess not `=` nor `*=` nor many others can be constant towards `this` instance

Comment: Heap corruption errors typically comes from going out of bounds of dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: By the way, are the loops in the default and single-argument constructors correct?

Comment: You need to give more information on where exactly this goes wrong. It's likely to do with your array member which is urk a raw pointer.

In passing you really should be using member initialisation lists. And your += etc operators shouldn't be const as they are meant to be modifying the object in question. Although you haven't tried to implement them so...

Comment: Also, do not ever put 'using namespace std; ' in a header file...

Comment: And for a possible cause of the error: In the `setCoeff` function, what if `abs(exp) + 1` is less than `this->largest_exponent`? What happens in the copying loop then? And you don't seem to have any bounds-checking *anywhere*?

Comment: You allocate memory dynamically but do not delete it. This happens, for example, in `setCoef` (you do not delete `array` member) and also in all operators (you create tmp objects dynamically but do not delete them). The code you wrote would work correct in languages with garbage collector, such as Java or C#. But in C++, you have to delete dynamic memory manually.

Comment: thanks @gudok .. i have changed my code to use only a temp array instead of using a whole new poly .. and cleanly delete the array after i'm done ... no more heap errors now .. thanks a lot for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains pretty much mistakes.

First, don't mark all operators as `const` if they are not constant. Assignment operator is never constant.

Second, you allocate your `array` member with a different size depending on constructor. Nice practice is to perform `assert` when trying to access array member to validate index is not out of bound.

Next, in your `setCoef(...)` you copy content of old array into new and if new one is smaller than old, you get your access violation:

```
...
void Poly::setCoeff(int coeff, int exp) {
    int* newarray = new int[(abs(exp)) + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= (abs(exp));i++) {
        newarray[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= this->largest_exponent;i++) {
        newarray[i] = this->array[i];  // HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
    ...
```

Also you dont `delete[]` your previous  `array` when you reallocate it it `setCoef(...)`